# Why toLocaleTimeString(), always zero-pad minute and second

Tags: javascript, time, locale, intl, time-format

*I use javascript [**Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) (or equivalently: [**Intl.DateTimeFormat()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat))*

---

I want a representation of time (especially **minute** and **second**) **WITHOUT leading zero** (when min/sec is less than 10).

Ex. **`13:2:3` or `1:2:3 PM` (NOT `13:02:03` or `1:02:03 PM`)**

But I can't achieve this:

```js
const date = new Date('2/21/2021, 13:2:3')

const t1 = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US') // 1:02:03 PM
const t2 = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timeStyle: 'medium'}) // 1:02:03 PM
const t3 = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timeStyle: 'short'}) // 1:02 PM
const t4 = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}) // 02:03
const t5 = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric'}) // 02:03


console.log(t1 + '\n' + t2 + '\n' + t3 + '\n' + t4 + '\n' + t5)
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#parameters):

> **minute**
>
> The representation of the minute. **Possible values are `"numeric"`, `"2-digit"`**.
>
> **second**
>
> The representation of the second. **Possible values are `"numeric"`, `"2-digit"`**.

---

***NOTE: I don't want to use an external library, for this.***

Comment: I think the distinction between `numeric` and `2-digit` is only relevant for years, where 2-digit leaves out the century.

Comment: @Barmar, Then why are they available for `minute` and `second`?

Comment: Why? This makes it stop looking like a time and is going to cause confusion.

Comment: No idea, I think it's just consistency for all the numeric fields.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to do this, but hey.

You can use [`formatToParts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) and remove the leading zero from whatever type you want:

```js
const date = new Date('2/21/2021, 13:02:03')

const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language, {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
});

const dateString = formatter.formatToParts(date).map(({type, value}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'minute':
    case 'second':
        return value.replace(/^0/, '');
    default:
        return value;
  }
}).join('');


console.log(dateString)
```